# Inserting an integer data in Database without Post (PHP)

Tags: php, database

I am a beginner when it comes to coding, but I want to automatically add these values to the database every time a person registers. When I try to enter the code all I get is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\ -----\ ---\ -------\register.php on line 16
```

Here is the code:

```
$level = 1 ['level'];
$money = 500 ['money'];
$current_health = 100 ['current_health'];
$max_health = 100 ['max_health'];

$query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($level)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($money)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($current_health)."',
        '".mysql_real_escape_string($max_health)."')";

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query))   {
            header ('Location: register_success.php');
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is  `1 ['level']` and all like that ?

Comment: What's `1 ['level']`, `500 ['money']`, etc.? Where do you get this from?

Comment: That is the default data I want to add to the fields.

Comment: 1 ['level'] this is not the right syntax what you are using and it is creating error. i think its not usable to remove these array notations.

Comment: 1['level'] is not a valid syntax here. It should be something like $array['level'] or $array[1]['level'] depending on your logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 ['level'];
```

this type of syntax is not available in php

remove [ ] with its content